# iOS QLPreviewController show pdf saved to file system

Tags: ios, qlpreviewcontroller

I have QLPreviewController working if I show a PDF file system from my bundle on the project,

like this [example](http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/preview-documents-with-qlpreviewcontroller.html)

but If I want to show a PDF from the file system, it doesnt show it, how can I call a pdf file that I have just downloaded in my file system?

The code:

```
- (void)initPDFviewer
{
    QLPreviewController *previewController=[[QLPreviewController alloc]init];
    previewController.delegate=self;
    previewController.dataSource=self;
    [self presentModalViewController:previewController animated:YES];
    [previewController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller
{
    return 1;
}
- (id <QLPreviewItem>)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    //return 0;


    //return url!


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSLog(@"paths :: %@", paths);

    return 0;

}
```

So my problem is how to get the pdf [only pdf in the documents directory], how do i get this pdf?

thanks

thanks!

Comment: Show your relevant code for accessing the file and setting up the `QLPreviewController`.

Comment: @rmaddy hi, thanks, i have placed the code, as you see, i dont know how to get the doc, thanks

Comment: Do you have a specific PDF in the Documents folder or do you need to find one or more PDFs in the Documents folder at runtime? If you have a specific then you get the full path by doing something like: `NSString *pdfPath = [paths[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sutff.pdf"];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your init method to below.

```
-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        //  arrayOfDocuments = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: 
        //          @"iOSDevTips.png", @"Remodel.xls", @"Core J2ME Technology.pdf", nil];

         NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
         NSString *docPath = [paths lastObject];

         NSArray *docArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:docPath error:nil];

         arrayOfDocuments = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:docArray];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Add this new method

```
-(NSString*)documentDirectoryPathForResource:(NSString*)aFileName 
{
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
     NSString *fullPath = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFileName];
     return fullPath;
}
```

And replace your method with my method

```
- (id <QLPreviewItem>)previewController: (QLPreviewController *)controller previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index 
{
      // Break the path into it's components (filename and extension)
      NSString *path = [self documentDirectoryPathForResource:arrayOfDocuments[index]];

      return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
}
```

Code is self explanatory. Just create the array of all the documents that are in your document directory. And after that use that array to create the path and provide URL of that path to QLPreviewController

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *fileURL = nil;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *wordFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.doc"];

fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:wordFilePath];

return fileURL;
```